# Push to repo failed (Git/GitHub)

Tags: git, github, push

I'm trying to push my files to a repo on GitHub, and I'm receiving an error. Could anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong?

An error message is being thrown, but I can't make sense of it (I'm new to Git...)

```
git push -u origin master

> To https://github.com/URL  ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch
> first) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://URL' hint: Updates
> were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not
> have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
> hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote
> changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See
> the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because on server you have changes that you do not have on local.

Follow below

1. Pull from remote `git pull origin master`
2. Push into remote. `git push origin master`

It normally happens when someone has pushed to remote branch after you have taken a pull. Thus, your commit history becomes different from server commit history. In such case, if git would have allowed you to push, the commit history on server (source of truth) would have been altered and also people taking pull from repo would have faced conflicts. Thus, your push is rejected.

However, if you are very very sure that the its a new repo and no one has made any changes to the master remote(as mentioned in comments below) run this git push -f origin master

Comment: Ok, that's strange because this is brand new repo, so no one else could have pulled from it, or interacted with it in any way. I have set up other repos with the same 'origin' though - could that be the problem?

Comment: No, that should not be the problem. Try seeing the output of `git log origin master` and `git log master`. 1st one is for remote branch and 2nd one is for local branch.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I'm now getting a similar error message, including this bit: `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`...

Comment: If you are very very sure that the its a new repo and no one has made any changes to the master remote run this `git push -f origin master`

Comment: force push. Just don't worry about what is on the remote, force push that I am pushing from local. Please mark my answer as correct, if it helped you :-)

Comment: Pleasure. Thanks.